Information_schema INVALID IDENTIFIER from snowflake when trying to access query history through a python script
I am currently working with Snowflake to view the query history. However, when I attempt to execute the same command in Python, following its syntax rules, I encounter an error stating ‘INVALID IDENTIFIER’ for ‘information_schema’.
select * from table(information_schema.query_history()) 

Usually these things can be resolved by simply advising the documentation, and reviewing the query profile from within Snowflake. In this case, please try using the following code, with snowflake specified instead of directly targeting the information_schema.
Other than that, also ensure your user has the correct and specified access.
select *
from table(snowflake.information_schema.query_history())
order by start_time

If your issue persists, please add as an comment what the query looks like from snowflake point of view, as what you're running in python might not be what is actually running depending on your lib.

Why does the documentation omit that you need to query the information schema of the "snowflake" database?

Documentation in general omits quite a bit. Especially if you start looking at account_usage, which is only present in snowflake db. The product is ever evolving, I think they have some painpoints keeping up with parts of it. Lots of inaccurate information we've come across in the past 4 years.

Also, Snowflake might not be the correct database in this case, I just used it as an example. Information_schema belongs to a database and unless you've got one selected, it will throw errors.

Thank you @Stoff This works well. Snowflake is the database. Snowflake documentation is bit outdated I guess.
